# Was bedeutet "auf den Inhalt des Protokollvermerks wird insoweit verwiesen" im Beschluss einer Vollstreckungskammer

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich habe gerade einen Beschluss einer Vollstreckungskammer übersetzt und bin auf diesen Satz gestoßen:

*Der Verurteilte wurde durch die Kammer heute persönlich angehört, **auf den Inhalt des Protokollvermerks wird insoweit verwiesen.***

Was bedeutet im diesem Sinn *verweisen auf* und *insofern*? Ich habe mir gedacht, dass nach diesem Satz das Lesen des Protokolls erfolgen wird, das ist aber nicht passiert.

Weiß jemand, worum es sich hier handeln kann? Könnt ihr eventuell die englische Übersetzung dem Kommentar beifügen?

Comment: Das ist in dieser Form keine Frage für dieses Forum. Das Forum kann nicht Bedeutung in krude Sätze aus bestimmten bürokratisch-administrativen Zusammenhängen hineinlesen, noch dazu ohne dass man den Kontext kennte (nämlich den erwähnten Protokollvermerk). Rufen Sie doch einfach bei dem fraglichen Gericht an und fragen Sie, was der Autor damit gemeint hat. Manchmal kommt man so weiter. - Ganz kurz und allgemein *könnte* gemeint sein: "**Siehe auch Protokollvermerk**". Könnte!

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine Antwort. Das ist nur eine Aufgabe, die ich an der Universität bekommen habe, d.h. ich erstelle hier keine beglaubigte Übersetzung, deswegen werde ich bei dem Gericht nicht anrufen. Ich erwarte auch keine professionelle Antwort eines Rechtsanwaltes. Meine Frage diente nur rein theoretischen Überlegungen nach dem Sinn des Satzes.

Comment: @Marcia "Insoweit" ist hier ein typisches Füllwort im Beamtendeutsch und kann ohne Bedeutungsverlust weggelassen werden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es ist ein bisschen problematisch, in krudes Bürokratendeutsch einen bestimmten Sinn hineinzulesen.

Ich meine jedoch, der Schreiber, der bei Gericht das so formuliert hat, hätte einfacher schreiben können:

> Siehe Protokollvermerk

Oder länger und in dieser Umgebung natürlich unüblich:

> Beachten Sie hierzu auch den Protokollvermerk.

Or in English simply

> See note below

Ohne weiteren Kontext zu kennen (zum Beispiel den Inhalt dieses Vermerks) ist das ein naheliegender Sinn des Satzes. In die einzelnen Wörter wie "insoweit" darf man hier nichts hineininterpretieren, das sind eher bürokratische Umstandskrämereien.